# Vagrant - Install Ruby Gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems, vagrant, vagrantfile

When run vagrant provision, instead of install the ruby gems in user environment, install in the root user environment.

Here is my vagrant file:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

config.vm.box = "scotch/box"
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
config.vm.hostname = "scotchbox"
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www", :mount_options => ["dmode=777", "fmode=666"]

# Optional NFS. Make sure to remove other synced_folder line too
#config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www", :nfs => { :mount_options => ["dmode=777","fmode=666"] }

config.vm.provision "shell", path: "provision/install.sh"
config.vm.provision "shell", path: "provision/install-gems.sh"
end
```

And the install-gems.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "- install sass ..."  
gem install sass
echo "- install sass done"

echo "- install compass ..."
gem install compass
echo "- install compass done"

echo "- install bootstrap-sass ..."
gem install bootstrap-sass
echo "- install bootstrap-sass done"
```

When i run `gem list`, the gems not appears, but when i run `sudo gem list`, they do, which i don't want to.

How can i in vagrant install the gems in not root mode? Try to add the `privileged: false` in vagant file, but not work because of privileges.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would believe the following works

In your Vagrant file

```
config.vm.provision "shell", path: "provision/install-gems.sh", privileged: false
```

To pass the privileges issue

```
gem install --user-install ....
```

Then the gems will be install for your user and will be available when running `gem list`

Comment: That don't work, because go to the sudo environment, not for the user environment.